# Can I carry a shofar to shul on Yom Kippur?

Tags: yom-kippur, muktzeh, hachana-prep-for-weekday

In a place that has an eruv, can one carry a shofar to shul on Yom Kippur (e.g. during the break between Musaf and Mincha)  so that it can be used at the end of neilah? or is there an issue of muktzeh, preparation for the next day (since the shofar blowing is at the end of the holiday), or any other issue?

Comment: on the issue of muktzah https://avodah.aishdas.narkive.com/IyKNQkwk/shofar-on-yom-kippur-muktzah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Shul they forgot the Shofar, and the Rabbi said it is Muktza. He said to send a Katan during twilight בין השמשות - to bring the Shofar from within the Eruv.

Based on this I would say it is prohibited to bring a Shofar within an Eruv between Musaf & Mincha.

Comment: Interesting pesak. You can blow the shofar during bein hashemashot... why would it be muktzeh then?

Comment: Since Yom Kippur, I've had several other rabbis relevant to me give the same ruling.

Comment: Perhaps it is Muktza until the time it is blown?

Answer (score 1):

The [Rama 308:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.308.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that Shofar is Muktzeh as a KLi Shemalochto Lissur:

> שופר אסור לטלטלו כ"א לצורך גופו או מקומו (הגהות אשירי סוף פרק במה מדליקין)

> It is forbidden to move a Shofar unless for the sake of using it or for using its place. (Ha'gahot Ashiri, end of Perek Bameh Madlikin)

Since it is assur to blow a shofar on Yom Kippur it would be impossible to say that it is being moved for the sake of using it and therefore would be muktzeh.

Comment: What about during bein hashemashot?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a shvus deshvus bemakom mitzvah?